# uploaded file permissions

Tags: php, apache

I am struggling with file permissions for uploaded zip files which are then unzipped and sorted into the correct directory.

For example:

1. user uploads FileA.zip
2. FileA.zip is moved to the parent/uploads/ directory (still zipped)
3. FileA.zip is extracted to parent/module1/FolderA (folderA is created at the same time the zip is extracted)

The upload and extraction process work fine, but I am unable to delete the `folderA` or any of the individual files it contains. When connecting with `SSH` or `FTP`, I am met with a `permission denied` error message.

The only time I can delete the folder or file, is when I run `sudo` in an `SSH connection`.

I also ran the `chmod($target_path, 0777)` at the time the file is uploaded to the server but I still experience the same file permission error.

Note: `module1` was created with permissions set to `0777`, but all the extracted files that are giving me problems, are set to `0644`.

What can I do to either set the permissions for each extracted file to **0777** OR connect via **WinSCP** to run **sudo** by default?

Answer (score 0):

sudo chmod 777 filename, also check the ownership of the file/directory you are trying to access. check logs for errors, it will tell you exactly why permission is denied

Comment: NO! NOT THE DREADED 0777! ANYTHING BUT THAT!

Comment: yea, there must be a better way to handle the files

Comment: I discovered that the files extracted to the new location have a different owner "daemon"

Comment: yes then change the ownership, thats what i said. sudo chown root:root filename. And without any positive answer why did you gave me negative points. I will report this..